# NotifyForFields what is the difference between Select vs Reference type?

Tags: query, pushtopic

There're multiple notification types for push topics defined by the field `NotifyForFields`. I'm trying to understand the difference between [NotifyForFields Set to Select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/notifyforfields_select.htm) and [NotifyForFields Set to Referenced](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/notifyforfields_referenced.htm), it looks for me like they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the difference between `Select` vs `Reference` that `Select` generates push topic notification only if any field in `Select` clause changed, while `Reference` will generate push topic if either field referenced in `Select` or `Where` changed.

The same query will generate push topic differently, for example:

```
SELECT Id, f1, f2 FROM Invoice_Statement__c WHERE f3 = 'abc' AND f4 LIKE 'xyz'
```

If `f1` or `f2` changed push topic will be generated for both cases. But if `f3` or `f4` changed only `NotifyForFields` type `Reference` will generate push topic, while `Select` type won't generate any push topic.